# ffmpeg - invalid duration

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg

For a project I'm working on I have a small bash script that loops over an input csv file of timecodes, and uses ffmpeg to create screenshots of a given film at each timecode. The csv file is in the format hh:mm:ss,id - it looks like this (extract)

```
00:00:08,1
00:00:49,2
00:01:30,3
00:02:38,4
00:03:46,5
00:04:08,6
00:04:26,7
00:04:37,8
00:04:49,9
00:05:29,10
00:05:52,11
00:06:00,12
00:06:44,13
00:07:49,14
00:08:32,15
00:09:28,16
00:10:17,17
00:10:44,18
00:11:48,19
00:12:07,20
```

I've used it without issue in the past, but today I've come to update some of the films and I'm getting a weird issue where ffmpeg is complaining that my input timecode is invalid, despite being in the right format.

The new input csv files are the same format as the old ones, but it seems like every so often ffmpeg drops the hours from the hh:mm:ss timestamp. If I comment out the ffmpeg line, everything prints to the terminal as expected (but obviously I get no screenshots).

This is my loop code:

```
while read code a
do
  echo $code
  f="$(printf "%03d" $i)"

  ffmpeg -loglevel error -y -ss $code -i $FILM -vframes 1 -q:v 2 $OUTPUT/$f.jpg

  ((i++))
done < $INPUT
```

I've tried all sorts, including padding the csv with extra 0s - which works until the hours tick over to 01.

[image: Terminal output]

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm scratching my head.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I'm not sure why, but I duplicated the id column to the left of the timestamp column.... so it goes id timestamp id. And it now works as expected.